# What executable does Microsoft Forefront use to manually scan for viruses?

Tags: anti-virus

In Trillian it asks for the executable to used to scan any downloaded files automatically.  My company laptop uses Microsoft Forefront Endpoint Protection on Windows 7.

My best guess would be:  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Security Client\Antimalware\MsMpEng.exe

Comment: By default, Forefront scans downloaded files, just like MSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your AV should already be scanned to scan on disk write, which would scan any incoming files no matter their source without need for the Trillian configuration, which is not required, BTW.